# StackBlitz Error in /turbo_modules/@firebase/database@0.6.6/dist/index.cjs.js: Cannot read property 'registerComponent' of undefined

Tags: angular, firebase, stackblitz

I've been trying to reproduce a problem in my Angular 9 app on stackBlitz. I've been having to add increasing layers of complexity to reproduce the problem, so please forgive the seeming unnecessary complexity of this stackBlitz example. However, I cannot figure out what the current error is; it's something I've never experienced in my local environment.

Error:

> Error in /turbo_modules/@firebase/database@0.6.6/dist/index.cjs.js
> (15370:39) Cannot read property 'registerComponent' of undefined

Stacktrace in the console:

> Unhandled Promise rejection: Cannot read property 'registerComponent'
> of undefined ; Zone:  ; Task: null ; Value: Error: Cannot read
> property 'registerComponent' of undefined TypeError: Cannot read
> property 'registerComponent' of undefined at registerDatabase
> (https://routing-angular-1dz9hr.stackblitz.io/turbo_modules/@firebase/database@0.6.6/dist/index.cjs.js:15370:39)
> at Object.eval
> (https://routing-angular-1dz9hr.stackblitz.io/turbo_modules/@firebase/database@0.6.6/dist/index.cjs.js:15395:1)
> at eval
> (https://routing-angular-1dz9hr.stackblitz.io/turbo_modules/@firebase/database@0.6.6/dist/index.cjs.js:15407:4)
> at eval
> (https://routing-angular-1dz9hr.stackblitz.io/turbo_modules/@firebase/database@0.6.6/dist/index.cjs.js:15408:3)
> at eval () at Qt
> (https://c.staticblitz.com/d/webcontainer.a32b752fbc9b442489b.js:15:30145)
> at
> https://c.staticblitz.com/d/webcontainer.a32b752fbc9b442489b.js:15:38799
> at U
> (https://c.staticblitz.com/d/webcontainer.a32b752fbc9b442489b.js:15:13565)
> at
> https://c.staticblitz.com/d/webcontainer.a32b752fbc9b442489b.js:15:13207
> at Object.eval
> (https://routing-angular-1dz9hr.stackblitz.io/turbo_modules/firebase@7.15.5/database/dist/index.cjs.js:3:1)

Stackblitz example:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/routing-angular-bnv6rm

If anyone has an idea what is wrong and/or how I might best approach troubleshooting on StackBlitz (sometimes, the errors and strack traces are not super clear), that would be awesome!

Comment: Running this for the first time shows `Can't find package:@firebase/app`

Comment: Please update StackBlitz.

Comment: Apparently, you didn't install `@firebase/app`. Once you do, your example works.

Comment: Thank you. I feel very silly. I was not seeing that error until I looked at it without being signed in.